# How to check regex string space string?

Tags: regex

I know that there are a lot of different regex questions out there, but I cannot find a matching one:

I need to validate an input field, which should contain a string + space + string. Inside the strings, there should all characters be allowed (ö,ä,ü,á,é).

**Valid examples:**

> a b
>
> George Michael
>
> This is gööd

**Invalid examples:**

> George
>
> Michael
>
> GeorgeMichael

So all in all, I want to check wether a person has written its firstname only or both, first- and lastname. I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Why `This is gööd` is valid? it doesn't meet the requierement `string + space + string`

Comment: `/\S\s+\S/` should do the job.

Comment: @Todo Does the definition of string exclude special characters? Or the other way around: Is a string limited to `a-z, A-Z`? If thats the case, I do not mean a technical string, but do not know how describe it a better way in english.

Comment: I asked about the 3 words in `This is gööd` that doesn't meet `one word then space then one word`. How many words are allowed?

Comment: What language are you using? Does it allow unicode properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should help you confirm that the person is using first and last name both (2 names, not three or more).

**Updated:**

This now matches third word too optionally

`\S+ \S+(?: \S+)?`

Working example here: https://regex101.com/r/Tpo8gy/3

Comment: Thanks @Nabeel, this does not cover `Usain Quadi Bold`, as these are three parts of a single full name. Can I add this case somehow using a `*` selector, so that it is valid as well?

Comment: plz check now @MarianRick

Comment: This is matching `12$-(' &"#### ?.?.?.;,;,;`

Comment: @Toto coz the question said: "there should all characters be allowed"

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a language that allows unicode properties (perl, php, python, ...), you could do:

```
\p{L}+\s+\p{L}+
```

That will matches two words in any lang separated by one or more sapces.

If you could have more than 2 words but at least two:

```
\p{L}+\s+\p{L}+(?:\s+\p{L}+)*
```

Where `\p{L}` stands for any letter in any language.

Comment: by seeing your reputation score i thought u knew regex too :/ not working: https://regex101.com/r/WguXZT/1

Comment: adding "*" in end will match more than 3 too, he needs first, middle and last at max only :/ why did you alter my edit man! you should have asked at least! duh!

Comment: @NabeelKhan:Where have you seen OP wants to limit to 3 words?

Comment: in his "valid" examples :)

Comment: @NabeelKhan: He doesn't say that `a.b.c.d.e` is invalid. You are extrapolating

Comment: he didn't say: this_is_something as invalid too, so we should let it match that too? lol, it's ok, anyway, im out, good luck :)